# The concurrence of angle bisector, median, and altitude in an acute triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

$ABC$ is an acute triangle. The angle bisector $AD$, the median $BE$ and the altitude $CF$ are concurrent. Prove that angle $A$ is more than $45$ degrees. Here $D,E,F$ are  points on $BC,CA,AB$ respectively.

This question was asked in 4th All-Soviet Union Mathematics Competition  in 1970 and the wording of the problem is same.

Comment: th diagram of the question is the same which is given in the answer below and the question does not miss any context as it is has the same wording in the  paper which I saw

Comment: We all believe the problem is stated in the correct way: the "missing details" are your thoughts about the problem. What have you attempted?

Comment: please don't keep it as an off topic.I presented as it is in the question paper and worked a lot on the problem.I searched on the internet and could not find anywhere but could not find the solution,so I posted the question on this site.It is my last ray of hope and I hope someone on this community will solve it

Comment: In [my answer to a duplicate of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1017403/35416) I have a formula for the locus of one of the coordinates, which might be useful in some applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Trig Ceva theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml) it follows that:
$$\frac{AF}{FB}\cdot\frac{BD}{DC}=1\tag{1}$$
must hold, or:
$$\frac{b \cos A}{a \cos B}\cdot\frac{c}{b}=1,\tag{2}$$

$$\cot A\cdot\frac{\sin C}{\sin(\pi/2-B)}=\cot A\cdot\frac{\sin\widehat{ACB}}{\sin\widehat{FCB}}=1\tag{3}.$$

Since $\widehat{ACB}>\widehat{FCB}$, $\cot A<1$ must hold, so:

> $$A>\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

(Thanks to @Blue)

[image]

Comment: From your (2), we have $a \cos B = c \cos A$. The Law of Sines allows us to write $a = d \sin A$ and $c = d \sin C$, where $d$ is the circumdiameter of the triangle. Therefore, dividing-out that $d$, $$\sin A \cos B = \sin C \cos A$$ so that $$\tan A = \frac{\sin C}{\cos B}=\frac{\sin C}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-B\right)}=\frac{\sin \angle BCA}{\sin \angle BCF} > 1$$ since $\angle BCF < \angle BCA < \pi/2$ in this acute triangle. This implies $A > \pi/4$.

Comment: If you don't mind can you give me a solution using plane geometry or coordinate geometry

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula: coffemath just gave a proof with coordinate geometry. Now it's up to you to accept the answer you like most ;)

Answer (score 0):

A coordinate proof: $A=(0,0),F=(1,0),C=(1,t).$ Then $E=(1/2,t/2),$ and let the concurrency point be $P$, and let $h=AC=\sqrt{1+t^2}.$ From $AC/AF=PC/PF,$ a fact about angle bisectors, we can calculate $P=(1,c/(1+h)).$ Finally $B$ is on the $x$ axis where line $EP$ crosses it, and we find $B=(h/(h-1),0).$ We are to show the claim: if $t \le 1$ then the triangle is obtuse, i.e. the angle at $C$ is more than 90. [This is the contrapositive to saying: If the triangle is acute, then the angle at $A$ is at least 45.]

Now start by noting that for $t=1$ we get $B=(2+\sqrt{2},0)$ so for $t=1$ so we get an obtuse triangle [angle at $C$ is >90]  since in this case triangle $AFC$ is an equilateral right triangle but triangle $BFC$ has $BF>FC.$

Next note that as $t$ is decreased from $1$ towards $0$ the angle $ACF$ is increasing, and also, since the length $BF$ is also increasing (the derivative of $h/(h-1)$ is negative and we're *decreasing* the parameter $t$), the angle $FCB$ is increasing. Combining these we find that the angle $ACB$, which was already obtuse in the $t=1$ case, becomes even more obtuse as $t$ decreases toward $0$.

*Alternate (non calculus) finish to argument*: Assuming angle $A=CAF$ is $\le 45,$ we have both angle $ACF \ge 45,$ as well as $h=AC\le\sqrt{2}.$ Also, the length $FB$ is strictly greater than $1$ if and only if $h/(h-1) > 2.$ Using just algebra, $h/(h-1) > 2$ is equivalent to $h < 2,$ so that since in fact we have $h \le \sqrt{2}$ it follows that $h <2 $ to finish the argument, since we have the angle $FCB$ strictly greater than 45, which with the other angle $FCA$ being at least 45 makes the angle $ACB$ more than 90, and the triangle is obtuse rather than acute.

Comment: I don't know the concept of derivative ,it would be very great of you if you give me proof using pure geometry.I need to submit the problem as it is given as homework

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula I just added a different finish to the argument, not using any calculus. This proof is still one in coordinate geometry, rather than simply "pure geometry", however in my opinion the answer already here by Jack D'Aurizio is already basically one of pure geometry...

Comment: thanq to coffeemath for the analytical solution